# Does Excel VBA object model allows for access to keyboard shortcut to VBA IDE menu items?

Tags: vba, excel

Does Excel VBA object model allows for access to keyboard shortcuts to VBA IDE menu items ?
(I would like to create additional item in menu and connect it with choosen shortcut)

For example code below returns "C&lear" which means you can access "Clear" item by typing "l" when the "Edit" group in VBE IDE is active, but you can also access "Clear" by typing "Delete" button alone :

```
Debug.Print Application.VBE.CommandBars(1).Controls(2).Controls(6).Caption
```

is there a way to find pragrammaticaly direct shortcut to item in IDE menu ("Delete" in the case above) ? I would like to add item to VBA IDE menu with new custom shortcut ?

```
Debug.Print Application.VBE.CommandBars(1).Controls(3).Controls(6).Caption
```

returns "&Immediate Window" but you could also access Immediate Window by direct shortcut "Ctrl+G"

Comment: Have a look at the VBEOnKey sample here: http://www.oaltd.co.uk/DLCount/DLCount.asp?file=VBEOnKey.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a way to find pragrammaticaly direct shortcut to item in IDE menu ("Delete" in the case above)

Yes, there is. Try this

```
Debug.Print Application.VBE.CommandBars(1).Controls(2).Controls(6).ShortcutText
```

This will give you `Del`

**Followup from comments:**

[image]

Comment: great, at the of "Application.VBE.CommandBars(1).Controls(2).Controls(6)." statement Auto List Members menu doesn't pop-up

Comment: If you are talking about the Intellisense then see the updated post. there is a way to pull that up ;) You may have to refresh the page

Comment: @Qbik: Autocomplete shows up if you `Dim` it properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim b As CommandBarButton
Set b = Application.VBE.CommandBars(1).Controls(2).Controls(6)
Debug.Print b.TooltipText
```

returns:

```
C&lear (Del)
```

Similarly,

```
Set b = Application.VBE.CommandBars(1).Controls(2).Controls(6)
Debug.Print b.TooltipText
```

returns

```
Export (Ctrl+E)
```